# ROS Answers SE migration: 3D voxel world

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi

i'm looking for some method to import a 3d voxel world into gazebo. in the tutorials I found only a way to import 3d meshes http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/beginner/mesh_import.

someone has already had these problems?

thx
augusto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/539/3d-voxel-world/) by [trigal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/125/trigal/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2012-12-20**:
which problems?

**Comment by [trigal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/125/trigal/) on 2012-12-20**:
i mean, someone has managed to import 3d voxel maps into gazebo? is something that can be done?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-01-11**:
What format is your 3D voxels?  How many voxels are you attempting to simulate?

**Comment by [trigal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/125/trigal/) on 2013-01-12**:
hi, thx for answering. the voxel map is in binvox format [http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Emin/binvox/) and the  full map i would like to use is about 100.000 voxels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo currently doesn't support 3d voxels. Feel free to create a ticket on bitbucket.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0